# Inductor degradation?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design, inductor

For SMPS, I would like to know if inductors degrade with time and frequent high current usage. The idea of this, is to determine the elements that are most likely to fail over time in a SMPS (for example electrolytic capacitors), so I can make them easily replaceable in my PCB. Thank you

Comment: Solder joints on hot components (e.g diodes) are a frequent failure mode (annular fail). Folding leads over is sometimes used to prevent this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only common failure mode of an inductor is overheating, which can be from too much current (saturation) or too wide of a pulse width. The insulation burns at the core and shorts out the magnetic field. Now you effectively have a 'short circuit'. Same failure mode as transformers.

An extremely intense overload can crack ferrite cores, but that would be part of destructive testing, way beyond core saturation.

Like metal film resistors, they have no natural enemy except excessive heat. No parts corrode if the core and windings are coated in epoxy or polyurethane. NASA counts on such parts lasting centuries in outer space in deep space probes. As you mentioned, electrolytic capacitors can and do have latent failure issues, especially cheap imports.